# Is play2-aerospike module available?

Tags: playframework-2.0, aerospike

creating app in play2 with aerospike as db. Is there any module avaialble in play2 to access aerospike db.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, sorry, presently Aerospike does not have a module or connector for play2. But you should be able to use the Aerospike Java client to integrate it with your app.

Comment: @Bharat Kasodariya - Please accept the answer if it answered your query :)